# Creating RSA keys from known parameters in Java

Tags: java, rsa, encryption, bing

I'm working on implementing Bing Cashback. In order to verify an incoming request from Bing as valid they provide a signature. The signature is a 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the url encrypted using RSA.

Microsoft provides the RSA "public key", modulus and exponent, with which I'm supposed to decrypt the hash.

Is there a way to create the Java key objects needed to decrypt the hash as Microsoft says?

Everything I can find creates RSA key pairs automatically since that's how RSA is supposed to work. I'd really like to use the Java objects if at all possible since that's obviously more reliable than a hand coded solution.

The example code they've provided is in .NET and uses a .NET library function to verify the hash. Specifically RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash()

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(spec);
Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
verifier.initVerify(pub);
verifier.update(url.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Or whatever interface specifies.
boolean okay = verifier.verify(signature);
```

Comment: Will Cipher take a public key in DECRYPT_MODE?

Comment: Yes, the RSA cipher implementation of most providers will accept a public key for decryption. They will even check for the correct padding. However, it is better to use a `Signature` instance. I'll update my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: FWIW, to create the necessary `BigInteger` for `n` and `e`, in case you have the two values in base-64 form (as is common with OpenID JWKS responses etc), use `new BigInteger(1, org.springframework.util.Base64Utils.decodeFromUrlSafeString((String) key.get("n")))` (or another base-64 library that supports URL-safe decoding) - emphasis on having `1` as the `signum` of `BigInteger`

Answer (score 3):

Use java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec. It can construct a key from exponent and modulus. Then use java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic() with key spec as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
  private PublicKey convertPublicKey(String publicKey) throws Exception{
    PublicKey pub = null;

    byte[] pubKey = Hex.decodeHex(publicKey.toCharArray());
    X509EncodedKeySpec pubSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKey);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    pub = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);

    return pub;
  }
```

This assumes the Public key is given as a hex string, and you'll need the [Apache Commons Codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

If you have the key in a different format, try the [KeyFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) for more information.

Comment: I'll have to check and see if we have that library or if we can get it. Additionally will the Cipher object take a public key in DECRYPT_MODE? This seems very backwards to me.

Comment: It will if you're using the Sun JRE, but not the IBM version.   Coincidentally, the an IBM JRE utilizing the Bouncy Castle crypto provider will also work.

Comment: It may seem backwards,but what you're doing is essentially decrypting the 'signed' hash. Once decrypted, the hash you computed and the hash given to you by Microsoft should match.

Comment: ...but this is the hard way of doing what erickson has done the right way.

Comment: My code above is perfectly correct (and works).  If the original poster has the key in a hex String (instead of modulus/exponent format), it's the only answer that will actually help him.  Ironic that I'm the one who got no points for it.

Comment: I understand what's going on now. It's an interesting verification process, really all I'm doing is verifying that the hash was calculated and encrypted correctly. Since essentially anyone can do this with no ill effect decrypting with the public key is fine.

Not to be contrary but Erickson's code was actually quite useful. While I appreciate your taking the hex encoding into consideration Erickson's code is a little cleaner. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: *If the original poster has the key in a hex String (instead of modulus/exponent format),*   
I know this is old, but, just commenting...  I think the question stated "I have the RSA key modulus and exponent".  So ... the code provided here won't help.  Unless there is also a way to get the hex string from the modulus and exponent.