# BigInteger to Key

Tags: java, security

Is it possible to convert a BigInteger to a Interface Key?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html

I am trying to implement the RSA algorithms, and am generating the keys myself instead os using KeyPairGenerator. However, when incrypting my message using Cipher, it requires a Key. I have tried casting BigInteger to Key, however this didnt work.

Comment: Apologies - I have added further detail to the question.

Comment: Sure thing, `Key` is not a `BigInteger` so you can't cast. Cast in Java is not a conversion operator (except for primitive types). You'll need to know the exact concrete class that implements `Key' you want to instantiate and that's probably going to be just the start of your research.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating RSA keys from known parameters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023549/creating-rsa-keys-from-known-parameters-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of creating an `RSAPublicKey` implementation from a modulus and public exponent.

```
KeyFactory factory rsa = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
BigInteger n = ... ; /* modulus */
BigInteger e = ... ; /* public exponent */
RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(n, e);
RSAPublicKey pub = (RSAPublicKey) factory.generatePublic(spec);
Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
enc.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, pub);
byte[] encryptedContentKey = enc.wrap(secret);
```

An RSA key pair is a private key *and* public key, each of which comprise several numbers in the form of `BigInteger` objects. Each key in a pair shares the same "modulus". The public key has a "public exponent", and the private key has a "private exponent". For computational efficiency, private keys are usually stored in "Chinese remainder theorem form", which includes additional numbers.

If you are encrypting, you need to pass a `PublicKey` to the `init()` method of `Cipher`.

If you are decrypting, you need to pass a `PrivateKey` to the `init()` method of `Cipher`.

(Some providers allow you to use a `Cipher` to perform signature operations, and use the correct padding when you reverse the keys, but this isn't recommended or necessary when the `Signature` class expresses your intent more clearly.)