# Generating Rsa public key from string

Tags: java, android, encryption

This is my server public key :

`UlNBMQAIAAADAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQABupDgHg710Jh4QwJriIdrY+6yyZme0e0FSQ1EFO3JEmiT+DXRLgU7CcgqGqLhosqYV7Rm1/H0I0ugFBk4zisPbgIb3epyMCcjnTgknRYddtIl9jNS8Z91/1SJ5bY0FkIRFJLHSCEcu1Un09w+gpWRoeAhSc87EMGngUZixAcyoDeYsW0mM1IlH44flo76wXERadmtAd9KFN0nYTjMwkIDyc5B9I2zvSjOQ+p54+6dl6o6nOalCWJg8V137ZMwQCk/4Tmp4C52d0AzYjEeU9gQowkrm7DgjLthd4ew/kY5a/8JfsWMJhajDPgzBV5fFJMbNL1h0fmtG8QpH5OtWukDhQ==`

And Encryption Code :

```
 byte[] publicBytes = Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY, Base64.DEFAULT);
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA"); //or try with "RSA"
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(txt.getBytes());
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

i get this error when i try to  encrypt :

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

what's wrong with this ?

Comment: it's hard code . how can i encrypt data using string public key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented, this is a proprietary Microsoft format for public RSA keys, [`BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB
PublicExponent[cbPublicExp]          // Big-endian.
Modulus[cbModulus]                   // Big-endian.
```

with

```
typedef struct _BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB {
    ULONG Magic;                      // identifies the type, e.g. BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC for an RSA public key
    ULONG BitLength;                  // size, in bits, of the key
    ULONG cbPublicExp;                // size, in bytes, of the exponent of the key
    ULONG cbModulus;                  // size, in bytes, of the modulus of the key
    ULONG cbPrime1;                   // size, in bytes, of the first prime number of the key. This is only used for private key BLOBs
    ULONG cbPrime2;                   // size, in bytes, of the second prime number of the key. This is only used for private key BLOBs
} BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB;
```

The values in `BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB` have the little endian format, the exponent and the modulus the big endian format. `BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC` has the value [`826364754`](https://retep998.github.io/doc/winapi/bcrypt/constant.BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC.html) or `0x31415352` as big endian and `0x52534131` as little endian. The latter corresponds to the ASCII encoding of the string *RSA1*.

The posted key is after Base64 decoding in hexadecimal format:

```
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
```

or separated into its individual components:

```
little endian   big endian
52534131        0x31415352 
00080000        0x0800     = 2048 bits
03000000        0x  03     =    3 bytes 
00010000        0x0100     =  256 bytes
00000000    
00000000

big endian
010001
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
```

The last two portions are the exponent:

```
0x010001 = 65537
```

and the modulus

```
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
```

In Java the public key can be created with the class [`RSAPublicKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/RSAPublicKeySpec.html). This class has a constructor that expects exponent and modulus, see e.g. [here](https://stephenhirst.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/load-rsa-keys-from-modulus-and-exponent-in-java/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547249).

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comment of @Maarten Bodewes, the following must be considered when creating modulus and exponent as `BigInteger`: Modulus and exponent are positive values. However, Java uses the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for the representation of integers, so that the first byte additionally contains the information about the sign (i.e. if the leftmost byte is larger than `0x79`, the value is negative). To take account of this, a `0x00` byte can be prepended if the leftmost byte is larger than `0x79`. Alternatively, there are corresponding constructors, e.g. [`BigInteger(String val, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int)), if the data are available as hex-strings (the sign is taken into account in the `string`-parameter as optional `+`/`-`), or [`BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,byte%5B%5D)), if the data are available as byte arrays (the sign is taken into account in the `int`-parameter). Since in the current case the data are probably available as hex-strings, the following is suitable (e.g. for the modulus):

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger("ba90e01e...5ae90385", 16);
```

Comment: Note that you need to use `new BigInteger(1, byte[])` for unsigned numbers such as those used by RSA...