# Authenticating signature created on c# by public key on java

Tags: java, c#, x509certificate, verify

I am new to verification and certificates etc .. 
I am facing an issue , that I need to sign a message on c# then verify the signature on java , the issue I ma facing that I am unable to load the public key on java on a (PublicKey) object using the Base64 string generated on c# , I used the following code to generate the private and public key on c# side

```
 CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "MyKeyContainer";
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

            string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
            string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("pub:" + publicKey);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("pri:" + privateKey);

            Console.WriteLine("Key added to container: \n  {0}", rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true));
```

then I used the following code to create a public key on Java side :

```
    X509EncodedKeySpec specc = new X509EncodedKeySpec(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64("BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAA......"));
            KeyFactory xx = KeyFactory .getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey ssx=  xx.generatePublic(specc);
```

note that I copied the base64 public key string from the c# console .
When I try to run the code on java side the I get the following exception :

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: invalid key format
at sun.security.provider.DSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
```

I need to find a way to generate private and public key on c# (and generate a .cer file for the public key) to load it on java side , or find a way to load the base64 public key string into a (Publickey) object on java side . please help !

Comment: The code `KeyFactory .getInstance("RSA");` and the exception does not correspond because is using a DSAKeyFactory instead of RSAKeyFactory. Ensure you are executing the correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: Same data, different format.

The easiest way to transmit a public RSA key from .NET is to check that the public exponent value is `{ 01 00 01 }` and then send the modulus value.  On the receiver side you accept the modulus and assert the public exponent.

```
RSAParameters keyParams = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

if (!keyParams.Exponent.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 }))
    throw new InvalidOperationException();

Send(keyParams.Modulus);
```

Then [Creating RSA keys from known parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023549/creating-rsa-keys-from-known-parameters-in-java) says you can straightforwardly recover it on the Java side.

## Option 2: Same format, different parser.

The next option you have is to keep using the CSP blob, but writing a parser in Java.  The data is the result of calling [`CryptExportKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379931(v=vs.85).aspx) with `PUBLICKEYBLOB`, making your data layout as described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee442238.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601(v=vs.85).aspx#pub_BLOB.

In summary:

A header (which you could decide to skip, or just test it for equal to the fixed value(s) that you expect):

- A byte, value `0x06` (`PUBLICKEYBLOB`)
- A byte, value `0x02` (blob v2)
- A short, value `0x0000` (reserved)
- An integer (stored as little-endian) identifying the key as RSA (`0x0000A400` or `0x00002400`)
- An integer (stored as little-endian) identifying the next segment as an RSA public key (a bit redundant, but technically a different structure now): `0x31415352`

After all that comes the relevant data:

- The bit-length of the modulus stored as a little-endian unsigned integer.  For your 1024-bit example this will be 1024, aka `0x00000400`, aka `{ 00 04 00 00 }`(LE).
- The public exponent, stored as a little-endian unsigned integer.  This is almost always `0x00010001` (aka `{ 01 00 01 00 }`), but since it's there you should respect it.
- The next `bitLen/8` bytes represent the modulus value.  Since this is the public key that should be "the rest of the bytes in this array".

## Option 3: Build a certificate

.NET Framework doesn't have this capability built-in (as of the current version, 4.7).  You can P/Invoke to [`CertCreateSelfSignCertificate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376039(v=vs.85).aspx), but that would involve quite a lot of change (since RSACryptoServiceProvider won't let you get at the key handle, so you'll have to P/Invoke all of that, too).

You could "bit bang" out the DER-encoded certificate yourself.  While fun, this is hard to get right, and probably not a viable path.

If you can move to .NET Core, the ability to create certificates has been added to .NET Core 2.0 via the [CertificateRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=netcore-2.0) class.  For a very simple certificate from your key:

```
var certReq = new CertificateRequest(
    "CN=SubjectCN",
    rsaProvider,
    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

// add any extensions you want. I'm not adding any because I said "simple".

DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
X509Certificate2 cert = certReq.CreateSelfSigned(now, now.AddMinutes(90));
byte[] xfer = cert.RawData;
```