# I have modulus and exponent with me how can I create public key in java or java script?

Tags: jmeter, rsa

Help me to solve this whether I need to install any package I need to use that public key for load test. Creation of public is not working in jmeter.

exp:10001
modulus:0086fa9ba066685845fc03833a9699c8baefb53cfbf19052a7f10f1eaa30488cec1ceb752bdff2df9fad6c64b3498956e7dbab4035b4823c99a44cc57088a23783

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating RSA keys from known parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023549/creating-rsa-keys-from-known-parameters-in-java)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [client-side certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/client-side-performance-testing-using-jmeter) - public key alone is not sufficient because you need a **certificate** in order to establish a trust

If you want to generate a public key from the modulus/exponent combination for whatever else reason - you can do this using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/), example code:

```
def modulus = new BigInteger('0086fa9ba066685845fc03833a9699c8baefb53cfbf19052a7f10f1eaa30488cec1ceb752bdff2df9fad6c64b3498956e7dbab4035b4823c99a44cc57088a23783', 16)
def exponent = new BigInteger('10001', 16)

def spec = new java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent)
def factory = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance('RSA')
def pub = factory.generatePublic(spec)

log.info('Public key: ' + pub.getEncoded().encodeBase64().toString())
```

[image]